# Word to describe someone who ignores your feelings or sentiments?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Someone who persistently overlooks your feelings or your sentiments. For example, if you show your love by all means and they appear to not care and take you as a joke.

What such person can be called ?

Comment: Well first of all I'd like to give you a hug. Then I'd ask you to clarify whether you're asking about a character flaw, even a mental condition, or an [attitude towards a single individual](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190026/term-for-someone-asking-for-a-friend).

Comment: An attitude of an individual

Comment: So what are we talking about?  She has one special boyfriend, and rejects shows of affection from all others?  And Ehaan is one of those others?

Comment: It should be noted that there are several medical/psychological conditions that can lead to behaviors such as you describe, though they would rarely be directed at just one person.

Answer (score 1):

You can call them **[indifferent](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=indifferent%20meaning)**

or

you can watch this movie:

**[He's Just Not That Into You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He%27s_Just_Not_That_Into_You_(film))**

Comment: lol that's funny. upvote

Answer (score 1):

You call that person "a [cold-hearted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cold-hearted) person" as it means:

> Without sympathy, feeling or compassion; callous or heartless. [Wiktionary]

Or you can call him "an [unfeeling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unfeeling) person":

> Without emotion or sympathy. [Wiktionary]

Or you can call him "a [self-centered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-centered) person" or "a selfish person":

> Of a person, egotistically obsessed with himself or herself.
>   [Wiktionary]

Yes, he is a [jerk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jerk) as Ricky posted in his answer.

> A person with unlikable or obnoxious qualities and behavior, typically
>   mean, **self-centered** or disagreeable. [Wiktionary]

Answer (score 1):

**cynical** is what I would call such a person.

> **CYNICAL**
>
> • of or relating to the belief that human actions are
>   motivated only or primarily by base desires or selfishness.
>
> • skeptical of the integrity, sincerity, or motives of others.
>
> • bitterly or jadedly distrustful or contemptuous; mocking.

[English Wiktionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/cynical)

Answer (score 0):

You can call that person a number of things:

- Insensitive
- Heartless
- Inconsiderate
- Cold-blooded
- Cruel

I would just call them an old friend.

Comment: You could, but those are very subjective answers. We don't know that any of those are actually true from the description given by the OP.

Comment: How is your answer "indifferent" any different? @chaslyfromUK

Answer (score 0):

Well, girls usually go with the word "jerk" preceded by any of the dozens of adjectives, such as:

unfeeling jerk, condescending jerk, arrogant jerk, self-absorbed jerk, conceited jerk, dismissive jerk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that such person is not feeling love for you and try to express it by being reserved (showing no familiarity or cordiality), you can say that he is **distant**.

*Example: I thought my parents were distant and unloving.*

Answer (score 0):

I would say that they sound **uninterested**.

> ***uninterested*** *adj*. not interested in or concerned about something or someone.